# NginX + Varnish + Iframe = Permission denied to access property 'document'

Tags: iframe, nginx, varnish

I am using NginX with Varnish FPC.

NginX vHost is running my site on port `8080` and Varnish is running on port `80`.

So, if I go to `http://mydomain.com` varnish captures that requests and grabs the content from `http://mydomian.com:8080`.

Having said that, let's say I have a `page.html` on my site with the following HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://mydomain.com/another_page.php" frameborder="0" height="100" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%" id="iframe" onload="autoResizeIFrame();" seamless></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
function autoResizeIFrame() {
    $j('#iframe').height($j('#iframe').contents().find('html').height());
}
</script>
```

So, when I visit the page at http://mydomain.com/page.html, it's meant to load the iframe and when the iframe loads, it will reize the iframe's height using jQuery.

This however does not work with NginX + Varnish due to same-orign policy.

This is the error I get in firefox:
[image]

I also tried to set the src of the iframe to http://mydomain.com:8080/another_page.php - but this didn't help either.

What seems to be the problem? and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

to the location segment of the server in the nginx conf

Comment: I tried it (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=r0gNgpZM) and restarted nginx and it did not help/work.